# Changing Windows 10 numpad mouse behavior

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse

My mouse is half broken, now I can't use my left click properly.

**Luckily** for me, I still have my keyboard. **The problem** is controlling mouse with keyboard is not as simple as it sounds like. Clicking and dragging with keyboard is not the same as controlling it with standard mouse.

Pressing the <kbd>5</kbd> numpad button will trigger the `mouseclick` event, while pressing <kbd>0</kbd> will trigger `mousedown` event. The `mousedown` won't let go until you press <kbd>.</kbd>, which is for `mouseup`.

This pattern is complicated, and kinda annoying to use.
Is there any way to change the behavior of these things? Like pressing the **<kbd>5</kbd>** button into normal mouse click, where it automatically follows the normal pattern: `mousedown`, `mouseup` then finally `mouseclick`.

Comment: You can either spend a week getting used to this, or buy a new mouse for 5 bucks. Your call.

Comment: I'll get used to this in 3 days then.
My mouse broke like 4 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I just switched to Linux Mint Cinnamon, and they had the functionality I mentioned above right **out of the box**, where you can trigger the `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mouseclick` with only pressing the `5` numpad button.

This solved my question, so I write it down in as an answer.